# In Rails where do I put the error detection logic to validate user input from a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a minimal rails app as a way to learn a bit more about rails.

The app is going to track stuff (books to start with). So I need a "Location" to identify where a given item is.

```
create_table "locations", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "located_at"
  t.integer "sort"
  t.string "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["name"], name: "index_locations_on_name", unique: true
end
```

`"sort"` is irrelevant for this question.

In the form to create a new location the user gets to enter a name (say "X") and optionally say where "X" itself is located (say "Y").

So to create the location in the controller I will do something like

`@location = Location.new(location_params)`

But I need to turn "Y" into a `location.id` for "Y". In addition, if "Y" doesn't exist, I need to raise some kind of error.

What I have now is a virtual variable `located_at_text` and in the controller I do this:

```
modified_location_params = location_params
located_at_text = modified_location_params["located_at_text"]
located = nil
located = Location.find_by_name(located_at_text) unless located_at_text.nil? or located_at_text.strip.empty?
modified_location_params["located_at"] = located.nil? ? 0 : located.id

@location = Location.new(modified_location_params)
```

(I don't know why I can't fiddle with `location_params` ... but that would be a different question ... I'll worry about that once I know where I'm best off putting my code. Also my app does't mind a `0` for `location.id`).

Various tutorials suggest that some of this logic should be in the model, but various examples also do similar work in the controller.

Which is the "rails way"?

Comment: "I don't know why I can't fiddle with location_params" - because this method returns a new hash every time. This was an hour of debugging I'm not getting back. :/

Comment: The rails way is skinny controller fat model(put all the logic in the model that you can).  If I am understanding your question correctly the rails way to do this would be to add validations to your model that enforce the behavior you wish to enforce.  Then, after you new up  your location.  try to save the location.  If it doesn't save then raise the error.

Comment: @ruby_newbie: fat models are better than fat controllers, but still have a fair share of problems. These days I'm a fan of extracting pieces of fat models into specialized objects. For example, validations go to form objects (coordinated by controller, as it is its job). The object needed for this problem, I'd call it a "params converter".

Comment: @SergioTulentsev.  I agree with the use of service objects as you mentioned but I think that adding that into this conversation would muddy the waters more than it would help. That said I tossed you an upvote for the suggestion.

Comment: I took a closer look at the code and... wat is happening here? Why do locations have other locations? Also you'll probably be bitten by the fact that your field is called `located_at` and not `location_id` (as per naming convention)

Answer (score 0):

I made some assumptions because not all of the example code made sense to me, but the basic outline would be:

1. Use ActiveRecord callbacks instead of checking input in the controller
2. Make sure relationships are correctly set so you can build objects from them
3. Use `first_or_create` to clean up the parent lookup/creation

---

In my experience, manipulating input params is a code smell. Sometimes you have to do it, but usually it's telling you something is incorrectly designed.

Some of the param manipulation you can accomplish with [ActiveRecord callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html). One note, it looks like `located_at_text` is not part of a model, you will need to check this in the controller or add an `attr_reader` to the model (but I don't think you should, this is another code smell).

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Set up the relationships in the model. This will let you build out the related records.

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :located_at

  validates :name, presence: true
end

class LocatedAt < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :locations
end
```

Normally, this setup would carry the ID for `LocatedAt` in the url (e.g. `.../#{located_at_id}/location/new`), but this isn't required if you are going to explicitly pass a located_at id which it looks like you are.

*This is outside the scope of your question, but if you are breaking from the url pattern where parent ids are passed in the url, it would be very useful for your users to give them some kind of auto-complete search or a UI element that lets them know explicitly that they are creating a new `LocatedAt` record. It will also make your life easier because you can pass in the id resulting from the search or a trigger param to create the new record first.*

Finally, use `first_or_create` to check that `located_at` exists (and if not create it). This assumes that there is only one field on LocatedAt and it is called `name`.

Note: I changed the model from Location since it didn't make sense to me that Location was going to look for itself in the example.

```
@located_at = LocatedAt
  .where(name: params[:form_name][:located_at_text])
  .first_or_create
@location = @located_at.locations.new(location_params)
```

Comment: {class Location < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end}

Comment: Please ignore the above comment ... I'm still getting used to the editing here ... and there doesn't seem to be a delete button ...

Comment: I'm not sure that a LocatedAt record helps. If I have Box1 that lives in Box2 that itself lives in Box3, now I'm going to need a LocatedAtLocatedAt.

Anyway, my basic problem is that in the form for Box1 I want the user to type "Box1" for the name and "Box2" for where Box1 lives, but the record should contain the id of Box2 and not the text of Box2.

So I use a virtual variable `located_at_text` to handle this and then some code performs the conversion.

Comment: @dampingwire If Box1 and Box2 are the same model (which they appear to be in your code and comment) you are not properly using relationships (neither the Rails Way or the RDBMS way). If you could provide more clarity about the schema and models, I could suggest a more Railsy way to handle it.

Comment: OK. I think I can come up with a minimal but complete rails example and supply all the code, but I can't put that in a 500 character comment. Do I start a new question and link it from here or do I edit my original question? Which would be clearer? Thanks.

Comment: @dampingwire editing the original would be better, no need for a whole app. Your db/schema.rb as well as the models would be useful.